# Sorting information from related tables - Symfony2

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine-orm

**A.** I have a table with users and a table with friends and here are their connections:

This in the **User** class:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Friend", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $friends;

public function __construct()
    {
        $this->friends = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

and this is in the **Friend** class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="friends")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $user;
```

I have an template, in which I render the friends of the current user just using

```
$friends = $user->getFriends();
```

But now I want to be able to sort the friends of the user. I created a repository class with this function:

```
public function findAllOrderedByName()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('SELECT f FROM EMMyFriendsBundle:Friend f ORDER BY f.name ASC')
            ->getResult();
    }
```

but it displays all the friends of all the users, not just the current user. Is there a way to show only the friends of the current user without using something like "WHERE friend.user_id = user.id"? If yes, please tell me how to do it.

**B.** Another thing I would like to ask is how to manage my controllers.

This is the action which renders the template to show all unsorted friends:

```
/*
 * @Displays the basic information about all the friends of an user
 */
public function displayAction()
{
    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

    if($user->getName() === NULL)
    { 
        $name = $user->getUsername();
    } 
    else 
    {    
        $name = $user->getName();
    }

    $this->get('session')->setFlash('hello', 'Hello, '.$name.'!');

    $friends = $user->getFriends();

    $cat = new Category();

    $dd_form = $this->createForm(new \EM\MyFriendsBundle\Entity\ChooseCatType(), $cat);

    return $this->render('EMMyFriendsBundle:Home:home.html.twig', array(
        'name' => $name, 'friends' => $friends, 'user' => $user,
        'dd_form' => $dd_form->createView()));
}
```

And I have a **sortAction**, but I don't know how to write it. It should be the same as the above, only the row

```
 $friends = $user->getFriends();
```

should be replaced with

```
$friends = $em->getRepository('EMMyFriendsBundle:Friend')
        ->findAllOrderedByName();
```

but if I copy it, it's a lot code duplication and it's stupid. I thought of one controller with an if-statement, but what to have in it? Please give me some ideas! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Friend", mappedBy="user")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
 */
protected $friends;
```

Comment: Thank you! But if I want they to be unsorted by default and have a special button to sort them, am I stuck with the WHERE clause and two almost similar controllers?

Comment: OK. For the where clause, why don´t you want to use something like  "WHERE friend.user_id = user.id"?

Comment: For the controller, create a controller with a parameter (displayAction ($ordered)) and use this parameter to decide if you need to call your new findby function or not

Comment: the WHERE clause you propose is simple and works, so why look for something else?

Comment: You will need to pass the id of the user to the findby method and use it in the where clause

Comment: It says that "Class EM\MyFriendsBundle\Entity\Friend has no field or association named user_id" :( It was automatically added when creating the database. Should I add it to the Entity file?

Comment: No, you should define the inverse (ManyToOne) association in the Friend entity

Comment: /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="friends")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $user;
Isn't it defined?

Comment: Ah, you should use WHERE friend.user = user